# WInston logger dynamic filenames

Tags: node.js, logging, nestjs, winston

Is it possible to use dynamic filenames for transport in Winston logger? I need to write a separate log file for each user. The problem is that transport filename is specified in the logger constructor. But when it initializes, I don't know how many log files will be needed, and it's names. So basically, I need to receive UserID in POST request, and write some log to file `userlog-<USERID>.log`. Or maybe there are some other libraries I can use for this purpose?